# Sending soap request through got library

Tags: javascript

I started using https://github.com/sindresorhus/got got package for http requests.
I try to use it for xml sending through SOAP:

```
 
 const xmls = "<test> <test>"
 try {
            const response = await got(someUrl, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "text/xml"
                },
                xml: xmls
            });
            return convert.xml2js(response, options);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Error: ${error.response.statusCode} `);
        }
```

It returns me 500, I've tried this request on POSTMAN and there it works. Does got support sending xml in body?

Comment: Shouldnt you declare response as a variable ?

Comment: 500 is a server side error. You will need to verify why the server is returning 500